# Model for balancing 2 sport teams with multiple players?

Tags: machine-learning

I need some guidance on what to start researching for this. I have 10 players and I need to auto-generate 2 teams. Every time a match is finished, I need to re-balance the teams. For that, I have two features:

- Win/loss ratio.
- Players that have better performance playing together.

Any ideas on which model can I use to get this automatic balance running?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is some lack of information on your post.

- Does it take long time to try a match? (can I do 10.000 simulations or matches in minutes?)
- What's your goal? Is to create teams that are as equal as possible?
- Do the players really have better performance when they are together or you are assuming it?

But, I will try to give you an answer:
If it takes long what you can do is shuffle the players and measure the win/loss ratio, that resumes all you need, statistically speaking you will be conducting what is known as a experiment. If the players really "interact" you will have to measure the win/loss ratio by pairs.

Comment: Hola Juan! Thanks for the response. I try to answer your questions to clarify the problem:
- I am trying to balance soccer teams that are going to play once a week, so yes, I take long to try a match.
- The goal is exactly that, to create teams as equal as possible.
- I am pretty sure player have different performance when playing together.

I was thinking about using the Elo rating system, but this wouldn't take into account two important things: 
1. Player interaction inside the same team.
2. Labeling player by position in the field.

Comment: I was getting some ideas from here https://blog.insightdatascience.com/hero2vec-d42d6838c941